# How to access component data with injected service without circular dependency?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a component containing a form in its template and also a [service injected](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-implement-services-and-dependency-injection-angular) in the component which would process the form data and handle an HTTP post to a back-end. I would like this service to access an object defined in my component class, since it would contain properties representing values from the form with two-way data binding (aka. [banana-in-a-box](https://akhromieiev.com/angular-banana-in-a-box-example/) method).

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975113/access-component-data-from-a-service) recommends injecting the component as a dependency in the service, but since my service would be injected to the component already, it would create a circular dependency error, so it is clearly not the way to go.

Is my approach correct by having a service for this use case or should I use a different design? If the former, how to implement without circular dependency error?

Comment: You could pass the data from the component into the service via method parameters. Why do you want to complicate things so much?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu but how would I access a method from the service in my component?

Comment: I advise you to go through [this wonderful "Tour of heroes" tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) that the Angular team built to facilitate the familiarization of new Angular developers and to showcase the most widely used techniques and practices of working with this framework.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Thanks for the tip, it was useful. Based on the tutorial you provided, I'll try to formulate a solution to my problem above.